# Calendar reminder is not giving notification before/on the event time

Tags: android

This event has been created in my google calendar but it is not giving notifications as per code. it should give notifications at the time of the event started.! All the entries that are mention in the code gets refelected in the calendar,event has been created, calendar is showing an alrm : At time of event, but still it is not giving notifications. 
please help me out?

```
public long MyCalendar() {
        long calID = 1;
        long startMillis = 0;
        long endMillis = 0;
        Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        beginTime.set(2015, 4, 29, 10, 51);
        startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
        Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        endTime.set(2015, 4, 29, 8, 45);
        endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();
        String eventUriStr = "content://com.android.calendar/events";


        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "My party1");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "surprise party");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE,tz.getID());
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
        Uri uri = cr.insert(Uri.parse(eventUriStr), values);

        long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());

        return eventID;
    }


    **And In onCreate() method of MainActivity, I am calling MyCalendar()**

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        long event_id1= MyCalendar();
                ContentResolver cr1 = getContentResolver();
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, 0);
                values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, event_id1);
                values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
                MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, values);
        }
```

Comment: post stack trace please...

Comment: it is not giving any error @ursgtm

Comment: Your beginTime is later than endTime.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. its working now @Arst